# How do I align an icon right next to "Click here"?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How do I align an icon right next to "Click here"?

I was able to use the below CSS to accomplish it but on a PC when using firefox, chrome, and safari the icons are not aligned.

```
<div class="link_container">
            <a href="#" class="click_action">Click here</a> 
            <a class="sprite_image action_image"></a>
            </div>


.link_container {
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.click_action {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sprite_image {
    background: url('sprite.png');
}
.action_image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -116px -12px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: without seeming too pedantic, you shouldn't use 'Click Here' Search engines get confused by the phrase. Search engine bots rely on a link’s label to identify that link’s content and match it with people’s search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to the .click_action and .sprite_image css:

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Allot of browsers hate - positioning, now everything looks good, but my thought is, make it part of click here, not a separate piece. Just add this CSS and your entire ahref and icon are clickable. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/DQJhY/)

```
.click_action {
    background: url("http://www.icondeposit.com/local--files/imageid:105/Preview-blue-set-icons.jpg") no-repeat scroll -6% 29% transparent;
    color: #999999;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 87px;
}
```